# When piping array of integers the $_ variable is null?

Tags: powershell, pipe

Take this as an example:

```
$var = "one","two","three"
0..2 | select-object $var[$_]

Index operation failed; the array index evaluated to null.
At line:1 char:27
+ 0..2 | select-object $var[ <<<< $_]
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArrayIndex
```

Why is $_ a null?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't figure why you are using select-object

try this:

```
$var = "one","two","three"
0..2 | % { $var[$_]}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use select-object in a different way:

```
$var | select -Index (0..2)
```

And btw, if all you want to do is extract element in the array, you can do array slicing:

```
$var[0..2]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use select-object you need to create a hashtable, aka calculated property,  and give it a name and expression keys. The result would be objects with one property, var, in the following example

```
0..2 | select @{name='var';expression={$var[$_]}}

var
---
one
two
three
```

Comment: This is not the right way that select *can* be used in this case. See my answer :)

Comment: it was a side note, +1 for using the index parameter.

Comment: That is why the can was in italics :)